# Typeahead.js bind selected option to textbox

Tags: typeahead.js

I am creating a quotation page and on this view a user can search for a suburb by its Name e.g. NAPIERVILLE; Pietermaritz and on select of the suggestion it must take NAPIERVILLE; Pietermaritz and append it to a textbox. All of this is accomplished using Typeahead.js

Please note that when selecting the suggestion the only words that gets binded to my textbox is:

NAPIERVILLE; Pi

[image]